# Image is overlapping with two column bootstrap class

Tags: html, css

The image is overlapping on the second column if the image is too large. I have the following HTML Elements for reference:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <img src="https://example.com/my-large-img.png" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    //My second column
</div>
```

Here is the output since the image is too large.
[image]

My resolve for now is adding a width on the image "img { width: 100%}"

The problem is I have a small image and I want to display the image on its regular size. Adding width: 100% will make the image stretch.

So If the image is larger than the first column I want it to be 100% of the parent width, and if the image is smaller than the parent width I don't want to make it width: 100%.

Comment: Like in... `max-width: 100%`?

Comment: Omg, thanks @AndreiGheorghiu max-width: 100% wors very well and it's responsive even on mobile. I didn't know about that. Thank you so much :)

Comment: you can try this bootstrap class <img src="..." class="img-responsive" >

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bootstrap class `img-fluid` specifically to give images `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` which you can add to an image like so:

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

[Bootstrap - Responsive images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images)